# Styling django filter form in html

Tags: python, html, css, django, forms

Here's how my django filter form currently looks:

[image]

And here's my html code:

```
      <form action="" method="get" class="form-inline">
           {{myfilter.form|bootstrap}}

         <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">
           Search</button>
      </form>
```

I am having trouble with the following:

1. How do I bring the filters in center of the page?
2. How do I change the "Name contains" to "Name"?
3. How do I change the color of text to white in order to make them more visible?

I have tried to search it online but no luckk. Little help will be appreciated. THANKS!

EDIT:

Here's my filters.py:

```
class WeeklyFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    Name = CharFilter(field_name='Name', lookup_expr='icontains')


    class Meta:
        model = Weekly
        fields = '__all__'
        exclude = ['Close','Score']
```

And my models.py:

```
Name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
Close = models.FloatField(null=True)
Score = models.IntegerField(null=True)
Result = models.CharField(max_length=200, choices=choices1,  null=True)

def __str__ (self):
    return self.Name
```

EDIT 2:

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### How do I bring the filters in center of the page?

**`form-inline`** is flexbox container so if you add **`justify-content-center`** it will center your form elements.

```html
<form action="" method="get" class="form-inline justify-content-center">
```

#### How do I change the "Name contains" to "Name"?

You can override **`label`** value of form field by specifying new value to it.

```py
Name = CharFilter(label='Name', field_name='Name', lookup_expr='icontains')
```

#### How do I change the color of text to white in order to make them more visible?

To make text white use **`.text-white`** class provided by bootstrap and specify it in your Django form by overriding attributes

```py
Name = CharFilter(
  widget=forms.TextInput(
    attrs={
      "class":"form-control text-white text-center",
      "max_length":"100"
    }
  )
)
```

So your final code for **Name** field will look like this

```py
Name = CharFilter(
  label='Name',
  field_name='Name',
  lookup_expr='icontains',
  widget=forms.TextInput(
    attrs={
      "class":"form-control text-white text-center",
      "max_length":"100"
    }
  )
)
```

Comment: It got to the center, Thanks! But i am having trouble with the text color. I don't have django forms only the models and filter. Kindly check the edit

Comment: @Johar Inam Unnar try by adding `text-white` class to form tag

Comment: @Johar Inam Unnar Did this solve your problem

Comment: It did, thank you loads. I am accepting ur answer. I a little favor, can u check the edit2 and help me space the items a little they look to compressed rn.

Comment: @JoharInamUnnar you can add `m-3` class to your form fields eg. `name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control text-white text-center m-3',max_length="100"}))`

Comment: m-3 gives me vertical spacing. I need horizontal spacing i.e. some gap between "name contains" and the search bar and "Result" so on. Currently, there is no space. THANKS

Comment: @Johar Inam Unnar than add `mx-3`

Comment: It works but max-length is correct this way since we are dealing with a dictionary
{'class': 'form-control text-white text-center',  'max-length': '100'}

Answer (score 0):

And if somebody are using django-filter library, can do it in html file:

```
...
{% load widget_tweaks %}
...
    <div class="col-10">
        {{ filter.form.somefield.label_tag }}
        {% render_field filter.form.somefield class="form-select form-select-sm" %}
    </div>
```

---

```
pip install django-widget-tweaks
```